# Абстрактные классы и композиция Java

Tags: java, ооп

Можно ли использовать композицию, когда оба класса абстрактные?
Например, у меня есть абстрактный класс `Тело` (от него я буду создавать `конусы`, `пирамиды` и т.д.) И есть Абстрактный класс `Основание` (то есть в основании `конуса` - `круг`, в основании `пирамиды` - `многоугольник`).

Как мне добавить класс `основание` в `тело` при помощи композиции. Я знаю, что создавать объекты абстрактного класса нельзя. Если есть способ, опишите пожалуйста. Если нет, объясните почему.

Comment: В Java нет множественного наследования классов, но есть множественное наследование интерфейсов. Исходя из этого вы не сможете отнаследоваться одновременно от Тела и Основания.

Comment: Со множественным наследием это да. Но я говорю про композицию.

Comment: Так же, как и любой другой класс

Comment: А зачем создавать ? Просто объявлейте с типом абстрактного класса, а создавайте уже позже

Comment: Кажется понял. Объект то не обязательно создавать. Можно потом уже в наследниках создавать всё что захочется. Верно?

Comment: @РамазанСаатов верно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract class Body {
    protected Base base;

    public void setBase(Base base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public Base getBase() {
        return base;
    }
}
```

Примерный вариант для класса Тело. Наследуя его ваша фигура может получить основание. Как вариант можно еще сделать основание default или protected, в зависимости от потребностей.

Comment: Я немного не понял как работает `setBase` и `getBase`. Я оставил `public Base base`. И потом сразу в классе его реализовал. Однако спасибо, я попробую разобраться в вашем решении

Comment: get и set методы необходимы для обеспечения доступа к приватному полю base. Если у Вас классы-наследники в том же пакете то можно private убрать и будет доступ к полю по имени а не через методы. Оставлять область видимости внутренних полей public очень часто не является правильным решением.